# Pandas -- how to iterate through a list of dates which filter a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas -- how to iterate through a list of dates which filter a DataFrame

I have a DataFrame 'numbers', like this:

```
         Date   group    Number
0  2013-02-01  group1 -0.098765
1  2013-02-02  group2  0.519878
2  2013-02-03  group1 -0.098765
3  2013-02-04  group3  1.960784
4  2013-02-05  group3  2.859412
5  2013-02-06  group2  1.960784
6  2013-02-07  group1 -0.696594
```

and a list of dates in another DataFrame, 'datelist', like this:

```
          Date
0    2013, 3,5
1    2013, 3,6
2    2013, 3,7
3    2013, 3,8
4    2013, 3,9
5   2013, 3,10
6   2013, 3,11
```

I am trying to return a new dataframe containing each record in 'numbers' where the date is <= datelist['Date']

I have tried this:

```
for date in datelist:
    end = datelist['Date'] 
    numbers2 = numbers[numbers.Date <= end]
```

but the for loop returns a single DataFrame which is the same as the original DataFrame 'numbers'.

```
         Date   group    Number
0  2013-02-01  group1 -0.098765
1  2013-02-02  group2  0.519878
2  2013-02-03  group1 -0.098765
3  2013-02-04  group3  1.960784
4  2013-02-05  group3  2.859412
5  2013-02-06  group2  1.960784
6  2013-02-07  group1 -0.696594
```

I can produce the DataFrames I need correctly if I enter a series of dates manually like this:

```
end = pandas.datetime(2013,2,26) 
numbers2 = numbers[numbers.Date <= end]
```

I won't complicate things by detailing the rest of this procedure -- basically, I am doing a Groupby on the 'numbers2' DataFrame by 'group' and appending the calculations to another DataFrame before moving on to the next date.

Can anybody point me toward the right way to do this with a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you want but I think you want to a sub dataframe (taken from the `number` dataframe) for each date in `datelist`. So in your example you want 7 dataframes created?

If so this is what I would do:

First turn the `date` column in `number` (I'll call it df) and `datelist` into `datetime64` columns. I'll assume the date column in `numbers` is already of type `datetime64`:

```
print df
        date   group  number   
0 2013-02-01  group1  -0.098765
1 2013-02-02  group2   0.519878
2 2013-02-03  group1  -0.098765
3 2013-02-04  group3   1.960784
4 2013-02-05  group3   2.859412
5 2013-02-06  group2   1.960784
6 2013-02-07  group1  -0.696594
```

And in `datelist`, I will create a new column that is a `datetime64` type (note I changed that dates in datelist so not all of the `dates` in the `number` dataframe were less than all the dates in `datelist` and I made `datelist` have less observations to reduce the size of the output):

```
parse = lambda x: datetime(int(x[0]),int(x[1]),int(x[2]))
datelist['end'] = datelist['date'].str.split(',').apply(parse)
print datelist 

        date        end
0  2013, 2,3 2013-02-03
1  2013, 2,6 2013-02-06
2  2013, 3,6 2013-03-06
3  2013, 3,8 2013-03-08
```

Now, I will just loop the rows of datelist and create a new dataframe each time through out of the rows where `date <= end`:

```
pieces = []
for idx,rows in datelist[['end']].iterrows():
  x = df[df['date'] <= rows['end']]
  x['end'] = rows['end']
  pieces.append(x)

print pd.concat(pieces,ignore_index=True)

          date   group  number           end
0  2013-02-01  group1  -0.098765 2013-02-03
1  2013-02-02  group2   0.519878 2013-02-03
2  2013-02-03  group1  -0.098765 2013-02-03
3  2013-02-01  group1  -0.098765 2013-02-06
4  2013-02-02  group2   0.519878 2013-02-06
5  2013-02-03  group1  -0.098765 2013-02-06
6  2013-02-04  group3   1.960784 2013-02-06
7  2013-02-05  group3   2.859412 2013-02-06
8  2013-02-06  group2   1.960784 2013-02-06
9  2013-02-01  group1  -0.098765 2013-03-06
10 2013-02-02  group2   0.519878 2013-03-06
11 2013-02-03  group1  -0.098765 2013-03-06
12 2013-02-04  group3   1.960784 2013-03-06
13 2013-02-05  group3   2.859412 2013-03-06
14 2013-02-06  group2   1.960784 2013-03-06
15 2013-02-07  group1  -0.696594 2013-03-06
16 2013-02-01  group1  -0.098765 2013-03-08
17 2013-02-02  group2   0.519878 2013-03-08
18 2013-02-03  group1  -0.098765 2013-03-08
19 2013-02-04  group3   1.960784 2013-03-08
20 2013-02-05  group3   2.859412 2013-03-08
21 2013-02-06  group2   1.960784 2013-03-08
22 2013-02-07  group1  -0.696594 2013-03-08
```

I concatenated the dataframes but you can process them by doing a groupby on 'end'.

Comment: Thankyou very much for this, Karl. Your understanding was spot on and this has enabled me to do what I need. Much appreciate your help, and also the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

First, I think datelist contain tuples or something like that instead of dates. 
After you make sure datelist contain datetime objects, you probably want to filter each record of first dataframe with corresponding datetime in second one. AFAIK they both have same size.

```
numbers2 = numbers[numbers.Date <= datelist.Date]
```

What do you think, does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks, muzhig, I had already tried that -- it is essentially the same as the two lines I posted above -- I added the variable 'end' for my own readability. It does work if I run it manually, but not in a loop. Also, you are right about needing to be the same size, and this is a problem too, as the first dateframe potentially contains multiple entries for the same date, and the datelist would just be  list of dates. ie they cannot be the same size. Thanks for your help -- much appreciated.